# Lync & Owa the integration problem

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app, lync

I tried the integration  between Exchange Server 2010 RTM/SP1 Enterprise Edition OWA IM with Microsoft Lync Server 2010.
But,when I login to Outlook Web Access 2010,I am receiving the following error.

```
 "Instant Messaging isn't available right now.The Contact List will 
 appear when the servce becomes available."
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The result of command "get-owavirtualdirectory |fl ".

```
RunspaceId : ca34da0f-3638-4c6c-87c8-01b81ff11199
DirectFileAccessOnPublicComputersEnabled : True
DirectFileAccessOnPrivateComputersEnabled : True
WebReadyDocumentViewingOnPublicComputersEnabled : True
WebReadyDocumentViewingOnPrivateComputersEnabled : True
ForceWebReadyDocumentViewingFirstOnPublicComputers : False
ForceWebReadyDocumentViewingFirstOnPrivateComputers : False
RemoteDocumentsActionForUnknownServers : Block
ActionForUnknownFileAndMIMETypes : ForceSave
WebReadyFileTypes : {.xlsx, .pptx, .docx, .xls, .rtf, .ppt, .pps, .pdf, .dot, .doc}
WebReadyMimeTypes : {application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.pre
sentation, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordproc
essingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.
spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/x
-mspowerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/x-msexcel, a
pplication/msword, application/pdf}
WebReadyDocumentViewingForAllSupportedTypes : True
WebReadyDocumentViewingSupportedMimeTypes : {application/msword, 
application/vnd.ms-    excel, application/x-msex
cel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/x-mspowerpoint, a
pplication/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wor
dprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocu
ment.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedo
cument.presentationml.presentation}
WebReadyDocumentViewingSupportedFileTypes : {.doc, .dot, .rtf,
.xls, .ppt, .pps,  .pdf,    .docx, .xlsx, .pptx}

RemoteDocumentsAllowedServers : {}
RemoteDocumentsBlockedServers : {}
RemoteDocumentsInternalDomainSuffixList : {}
FolderPathname :
Url : {}
LogonFormat : PrincipalName
 ClientAuthCleanupLevel : High
FilterWebBeaconsAndHtmlForms : UserFilterChoice
 NotificationInterval : 120
DefaultTheme :
UserContextTimeout : 60
ExchwebProxyDestination :
VirtualDirectoryType :
 OwaVersion : Exchange2010
ServerName : EXCH
 InstantMessagingCertificateThumbprint : 525BEB1EF6C2FA3C47CA503E7AFEFE15D3E71A74
InstantMessagingServerName : lync.unipa.com.tr
RedirectToOptimalOWAServer : True
DefaultClientLanguage : 0
LogonAndErrorLanguage : 0
 UseGB18030 : False
UseISO885915 : False

 InstantMessagingType : Ocs
 Exchange2003Url :
 FailbackUrl :
 LegacyRedirectType : Silent
 Name : owa (Default Web Site)
 InternalAuthenticationMethods : {Basic, Fba}
 MetabasePath : IIS://EXCH.unipa.com.tr/W3SVC/1/ROOT/owa
 BasicAuthentication : True
 WindowsAuthentication : False
 DigestAuthentication : False
 FormsAuthentication : True
 LiveIdAuthentication : False
 DefaultDomain :
 GzipLevel : High
 WebSite : Default Web Site
 DisplayName : owa
  Path : C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\owa

InternalUrl : https://exch.unipa.com.tr/owa
 ExternalUrl : https://exch.unipa.com.tr/owa
 ExternalAuthenticationMethods : {Fba}

  DistinguishedName : CN=owa (Default Web Site),CN=HTTP,CN=Protocols,
  CN=EXCH,CN=Servers
  ,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administra
  tive Groups,CN=UNIPA,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configu
   ration,DC=unipa,DC=com,DC=tr
  Identity : EXCH\owa (Default Web Site)
   Guid : 479d141e-67c3-45ec-b4e0-9b9f85d8515f
  ObjectCategory : unipa.com.tr/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-OWA-Virtual-Directory
  ObjectClass : {top, msExchVirtualDirectory, msExchOWAVirtualDirectory}
   WhenChanged : 05.05.2011 09:26:23
    WhenCreated : 11.04.2011 10:31:36
 WhenChangedUTC : 05.05.2011 06:26:23
 WhenCreatedUTC : 11.04.2011 07:31:36
   OrganizationId :
 OriginatingServer : core.unipa.com.tr
   IsValid : True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you setup the trusted application pool in Topology builder?  You can also use the Lync management shell.  See this link:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg420962.aspx